# Internationally recognized patent

Tags: international, utility

I want to file a  Utility patent with the USPTO that will be globally recognized. How and where do I get started? Can I file it online?

Answer (score 1):

If by "globally recognized" you mean that it will turn up in a patent search done most anywhere, then I would ask the USPTO for early publication and make sure the abstract has all the keywords someone would use in looking for it. If you mean a "globally enforceable" patent right, there is no such thing. Each county's courts can enforce their patents, under their laws, on what is done within their borders.

There is such a thing as an international **application** for a patent. It is called a PCT application and one does file it in one's own country's patent office. It is a way to simultaneously initiate an application in 140+ locations. At a set later time, you actually have to decide which places you are really going into, pay more money per location and deal with the patent office and patent laws in each of those countries.